# Find Number of LineBreaks in String and Get Count of the LineBreaks in String C#

Tags: c#

Could anyone please suggest how to find count of linebreaks in a string. Current in the below example code I have two breaklines. So how can I print showing number as 2

`String Str = "Hello <br /> How are You <br />"`

Thanks!

Comment: http://www.dotnetperls.com/string-occurrence\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var count = Str.Split(new[] { "<br />" }, StringSplitOptions.None).Length - 1;
```

Comment: This will give 3 for the example input.

Comment: Already corrected it :)

Comment: Simple and effective solution, but what about tags "<br/>" "<br lot_of_spaces_here                    />" ?

Comment: Also Can Try this code '
            string str = "how <br> are <br> you <br> sdfdsfds";

            string ptn = "<br>";

            int c = Regex.Matches(str, ptn, RegexOptions.None).Count;'

Comment: unfortunately it won't work: pattern is incorrect

Comment: It works for the example input, but for many other cases it is wrong. For example, if several line break appears in series (like "<br /><br /><br />") or any trailing text is added to the example.

Comment: @mikez You are correct.  I have modified my answer to support your example.

Comment: @JefferyKhan OK now you get +1

Answer (score 4):

Here's what you need:

```
    String Str = @"Hello <br/> How do you feel about strange but valid <br          

                 />
                 tags?";
    var regex = new Regex(@"<br\s*/>");
    System.Console.WriteLine("Line breaks: {0}", regex.Matches(Str).Count);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
//split the string
string[] splitted = Str.Replace("<br/>", "\n").Split('\n')
//output
int Count = splitted.Length
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        int pos = -1;
        int count =0;
        do
        {
            pos = Str.IndexOf(@"<br />", ++pos);
            if (pos != -1)
                count++;

        } while (pos != -1);

        Console.WriteLine(count);  //2
```